# inspect.getsource() and __file__ both don't work with pytest?

Tags: pytest

When I use either of these:

```
inspect.getsource(someObj)
```

or

```
__file__
```

These two work fine without pytest, but fail when the same code is run with pytest. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  inspect.getsource(pytest) or inspect.getsource(pytest.raises) works fine.  Could you provide an example?

Comment: Try putting them in a separate file and reference code in that file i.e. in the client code being tested, rather than the code with the test cases. The pytest run behaves different from a non-pytest run of that client code.

Comment: Sorry, but could you reference a paste / an explicit example of what does not work for you?

Comment: pytest "collects" the files and parses it for running as a test. It's an abstraction above python. It does modify a lot of objects. You should drop into debugger and try running inspect or __file__. That will give you more idea about the changes pytest make to namespace.